# how do I get blocks to teleport in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-commands

i am building Jurassic Park in Minecraft and i want the huge gate like door/entrance to open and close when i pass over a piece of the rail in a minecart. I have no idea how to use the codes. Im trying to get the blocks to teleport 90 degrees and then back.

Comment: Which game are you playing? Minecraft Java edition, Minecraft bedrock edition, Minecraft legacy console edition, …?

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are static and cannot be teleported as entities. This means that you will have to manually animate the gate using /fill, /setblock and/or /clone. Take a look at this tutorial on how to animate builds:

.

For the minecart detection, you can detect the minecart at some specific coordinates where the rails go:

```
/execute if entity @e[type=minecart,x=,y=,z=,distance=..1] run <trigger_animation>
```

fill in the coordinates and replace "trigger_animation" with how you want to trigger your animation (the classic way is to /setblock a redstone block).